# How to get a list of the views in the currently showing Layoutaa

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

Is there any way to get a list or array of the entire views being displayed on the showing layout?

In other words, since I have access to R.layout.myLayout, how can I get a list/array contains all the Views inside the layout?

Answer (score 0):

You can inflate the layout using a `LayoutInflater` and its `inflate()` methods. These will return the root `View` of the view hierarchy, and you can traverse the tree from there.

You can try using `getXml()` on a `Resources` object, to obtain an `XmlPullParser` implementation, to walk the XML. This works for plain XML resources (i.e., in `res/xml/`), but reportedly works with some other resource types encoded in XML. I do not know how reliable it is.

In either case, you are walking a tree. A layout is not merely a single list of widgets.

Comment: thank you. (1): I tried the following LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_main, null);
        view.getResources().getXml(R.layout.act_main);..but R.layout.act_main is underscored with red as an error, so i changed this parameter to R.id.myTextView and I get the same result

Comment: @LetsamrIt: Your IDE will hopefully give you a clue as to why that is in red. Make sure that there actually is an `act_main` layout resource. `R.id.myTextView` will not work, as that is not the identifier of a layout resource.

Comment: the IDE says:view.getResources().getXml(R.layout.act_main); expected resource of type xml

Comment: @LetsamrIt: OK, they added some rules for `getXml()` to limit it to true XML resources (the ones in `res/xml/`), so you would either need to try ignoring that Lint warning, use `LayoutInflater`, or find some other solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve.